# How to merge objects present in two different arrays into a single array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is an example structure of a document:

```
{
   userName:"herobrewer555",
   recentBrews:[{_id:1, name:'Watermelon wine', wortRating:'D6Z'}, {_id:2, name:'Pineapple wine', wortRating:'A5Z'}, {_id:3, name:'Banana mead', wortRating:'C6U'}],
   brewDetails:[{_id:1, mainIngredient:'watermelon', sugarSource:"white sugar"}, {_id:2, mainIngredient:'pineapple', sugarSource:"white sugar"}, {_id:3, mainIngredient:'banana', sugarSource:"honey"}]
}
```

Is it possible to merge objects inside `recentBrews` and `brewDetails` based on their `_id` like below?

```
{
    userName:"herobrewer555",
    recentBrews:[{_id:1, mainIngredient:'watermelon', sugarSource:"white sugar", name:'Watermelon wine', wortRating:'D6Z'}, {_id:2, mainIngredient:'pineapple', sugarSource:"white sugar", name:'Pineapple wine', wortRating:'A5Z'},{_id:3, mainIngredient:'banana', sugarSource:"honey",  name:'Banana mead', wortRating:'C6U'}]
}
```

In some cases there is an index correspondence between the two arrays, i.e, the first object in `recentBrews` and the first object in `brewDetails` will always refer the same brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `recentBrews` array
- `$filter` get matching object from `brewDetails` array
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from above `$filter` result
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object and returned object from `$arrayElemAt`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      userName: 1,
      recentBrews: {
        $map: {
          input: "$recentBrews",
          as: "r",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$r",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$brewDetails",
                      cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$r._id"] }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/emln5vxX5z7)